# Can someone help me with an if statement? The result is true, but the event will not fire

Tags: jquery, if-statement, xmlhttprequest, logic

I am retrieving data that displays a value of true in the console, but when I set up an if statement

```
if (onLive == true) {
 alert ("is working")
 }
```

the alert does not fire.  Can anyone help me?  Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/8j947/

Comment: Is it possible that onLive has a text value of "true"?

Comment: Next time do: alert(onLive) and you will see what the value is.

Comment: @DOK yes if it is a text value would I fix this by putting quotes around the true?

Comment: For one thing you need to select jQuery as your framework in jsFiddle - though I assume you're not developing in jsFiddle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isLive` is `"true"` (a string containing the word `true`), not `true` (a boolean value).

Comment: So it is a text value, is there a way to set up a logic statement where if the text value = true then do something?  Would I fix this with quotes around the true?

Answer (score 3):

Works like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/8j947/3/

You forgot to insert jQuery. And isLive returns 'true' a string, not a boolean!
You can check it like this:

```
if (isLive == 'true') {
      alert('working');
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just threw the code in there without changing jquery.  Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

the var isLive specifically needs to compare boolean values. In this case, you might want to check what type it is comparing. I am quite sure that it is not a bool comparison. Secondly, as previously mentioned, the statement can be 
if(isLive=='true')
{
....
}
Hope This Helps